# Extract the data from the data-frame using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have following data-frame.

```
PredictedFeature    Document_IDs                                   did  avg
   2000.0          [160, 384, 3, 217, 324, 11, 232, 41, 377, 48]    11  0.6
 2664.0        [160, 384, 3, 217, 324, 294,13,11]                     13  0.9
```

SO, like this I have a  dataframe which has more data like this.  Now, what I am trying is I have this `did column` in which I have `Id` ,

Now there is one more column `Document_IDs`, which has `id's` , so, I want to check weather the `11` document ID is present in this `Document ID's` column which is an array like wise .

So, like,

Final output would be like ,

```
 did   avg  present    
   11   0.6    2
   13   0.9    1
```

2 is 2 times document id 11 is present in this `Document Id's column`.

I am totally new to this. So any small help will be great .

Answer (score 1):

You can extract column `Document_IDs` with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html), then flatten values by `chain.from_iterable`, so possible `sum` matched values in generator with `apply`:

```
import ast
from  itertools import chain

df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].fillna('[]').apply(ast.literal_eval)

s = list(chain.from_iterable(df.pop('Document_IDs')))

df['pres'] = df['did'].map(lambda x: sum(y == x for y in s))
print (df)
   PredictedFeature  did  avg  pres
0            2000.0   11  0.6     2
1            2664.0   13  0.9     1
```

Or:

```
import ast
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].fillna('[]').apply(ast.literal_eval)

df['pres'] = df['did'].map(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df.pop('Document_IDs'))))
print (df)
   PredictedFeature  did  avg  pres
0            2000.0   11  0.6     2
1            2664.0   13  0.9     1
```

EDIT:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def literal_eval_cust(x):
    try:
        return literal_eval(x)
    except Exception:
        return []


df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].apply(literal_eval_cust)
```

Comment: data type of the Document_ID is object. while flatting it is giving me an error. 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - What is `print (type(df.loc[1, 'Document_IDs']))` ?

Comment: <class 'str'> this is what I get

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - So use `df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` before my solution

Comment: malformed node or string: nan

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - Added new solution, replace `df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` with `df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].apply(literal_eval_cust)`

Comment: @ganeshkaspate - Another idea is use `df['Document_IDs'] = df['Document_IDs'].fillna('[]').apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `Counter` and `map`

```
import collections
c = collections.Counter(df.Document_IDs.sum())    
df['Present'] = df.did.map(c)

df[['did', 'avg', 'Present']]

Out[584]:
   did  avg  Present
0  11   0.6  2
1  13   0.9  1
```

Comment: @jezrael: thanks for pointing out error in previous solution. I switched to `Counter` :)

Comment: Ya, it is better, only for performance `sum` is worse solution for flattening list (but look nicest ;))

Comment: @jezrael: hehe... I agree. I like its simplicity :). `itertools.chain` is the best for flattening list, so I already upvoted yours on it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a pandas native solution, try this:

```
df['pres'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(x['Document_IDs']).count(x['did']), axis=1)
```

I have not tested for calculation speed.

Comment: Hey I am getting this error "'float' object is not iterable", 'occurred at index 56')

Answer (score 0):

You can also count instances of an item in a list.

For example `mylist.count(item)`

So I would create a function to apply this to the rows:

```
def get_id(row):

    res = x['Document_IDs'].count(x['did'])

    return res
```

Then apply it, creating a new `result` column.

```
df['result'] = df.apply(get_id,axis=1)
```

Although I'm sure somebody will come along with a faster version :)

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[[3,4,5,6,3,3,5,4], 3], [[1,4,7,8,4,5,1], 4]], columns=['Document_IDs','did'])
```

In one line:

```
df['Present'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.Document_IDs.count(row.did), axis=1)
```

If you want to print the results that interest you:

```
print(df[['did', 'avg', 'Present']])

   did  avg  Present
0    3  0.6        3
1    4  0.8        2
```